# сделать запрос транзакцию на основе задачи!

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, transaction

```
задача такая! у меня есть таблица Order с столбцами: ID, Name, Price, Bonus.
```

нужно написать запрос (транзакцию) где бы вносилось 10 рублей в Bonus где Price 200. 
также нужно учесть чтобы при запуске запроса не добавлялись бонусы уже в ту строку где было уже добавлено Bonus.
но если один раз было добавлено 10 рублей где цена была 200 и пользователь снова сделал покупку на 200 ему снова должны начислить 10 рублей.
как написать такой запрос ?? я так понимал без transaction log которых не обойтись? но как??

Comment: не понятно что значит что то вносится в bonus, что находится в этом поле до этого, если там изначально не 0 то как определить был бонус или нет. никакой необходимости городить что то сложное с транзакциями не вижу, все сводится по идее к одному элементарному update, который заведомо атомарен

Comment: @Mike нет! не подойдет так как при запуске снова Update запроса получается добавлять бонус поэтому кому уже добавлялись бонусы раньше! как сделать так чтобы запоминались действия кому уже насчитали бонусы и при повторном запросе ему снова не начислять. так получается что одному человеку будет постоянно начислять бонус даже если он раз сделал покупку на 200

Comment: Но вы же в условиях update можете написать подзапрос, который проверит, что ранее для данного покупателя бонуса еще не выплачивалось по всей БД, а не только по обновляемой записи. Если вы конечно об этом пытаетесь сказать, что это как то можно понять по другим записям. Правда в вопросе вы так и не написали как именно это понимать, поэтому ответ на вопрос до сих пор не возможен

Comment: @Mike я незнаю как это сделать но задача передо мной стоит сделать transaction запрос! вы можете написать как бы это примерно выглядела сама транзакция? говорят что transaction log будет подсказкой как это сделать

Comment: кто же такое говорит, transaction log это средство за счет которого БД обеспечивает работу транзакций. вы не можете непосредственно им управлять или его использовать. кроме того, _любой_ запрос, изменяющий данные использует транзакцию, по другому быть просто не может. поэтому термина transaction запрос не существует ибо это масло маслянное

Comment: А когда говорят что надо использовать транзакции обычно подразумевается, что работу нельзя сделать одним запросом и приходится использовать несколько запросов. С этой точки зрения создать transaction запрос невозможно ввиду того что запросов должно быть больше одного

Comment: С третьей стороны, может тот кто говорил слова transaction log имел ввиду не transaction log БД, а то что вы должны где то в отдельной таблице сохранять журнал всех начислений бонусов и впоследствии им пользоваться. это бы имело смысл. но это вы должны отразить в своем вопросе с указанием структуры этого журнала. тогда возвращаемся к моему первому вопросу: каким образом узнать, что бонус уже начислялся

Comment: Ладно уж, хватит над студентами издеваться. Открывайте транзакцию begin transaction, выбирайте тип изоляции isolation level, выполняйте действия над данными, звтем закрывайте транзакцию.commit или откатывайте rollback. Ну или можно обработчиком сделать try, catch. Но в вашем случае вряд-ли пригодится.